# Toggle removes text, show/hide keeps it

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

This isn't so much a question to help me figure out a problem as it is one to help me figure out why the fix I came up with works.

I have some elements on a page which are created with jquery after loading some data with ajax.  I have a checkbox which is supposed to toggle the visibility of some of these elements.  When I tried using JQuery's .toggle() function, the elements would disappear properly, but when they came back, they were empty!

I decided to try show/hide instead (based on the checkbox's value) and for some reason, it works perfectly! I don't understand why, though, and I was wondering if somebody could explain it to me, for future reference.  Here is my code (working, with faulty stuff commented out):

```
$("#fbfeed").click(function(){
    //$(".fbcheckin").toggle(); // This killed my text.
    if($("#fbfeed").attr("checked")!="checked") $(".fbfeed").hide();
    else $(".fbfeed").show();
});
```

Thanks in advance for any responses! :-)

### EDIT

I definitely forgot to mention something.  The faulty code I left in the comment is actually technically valid in that there are ".fbcheckin" elements as well, that I'm also doing this to. I forgot to change it back before posting my code, but I switched the selector to see if I had the same problems with those elements. Which I did.

Sorry for the confusion! :-\

Comment: It looks like you used the wrong selector with `.toggle()`.

Comment: Do you have the HTML? It looks like you're toggling a different class from what you're showing + hiding.

Comment: Yea, why is selector in the commented out code different from the uncommented "fix"?

Comment: Sorry! I definitely forgot to explain that :-( That code is still valid, as there are elements with the class "fbcheckin" on my page which reacted the same way to "toggle". Regardless of which elements I use the code on, toggle removes the text and won't show it again, whereas the hide/show combo does things properly.

Comment: `$.toggle()` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PDp2V/

Comment: @esqew you will notice that I mentioned that I'm toggling elements that were created by jQuery after loading some data through ajax. These don't always react the way you expect them to. I believe they aren't actually added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've been toggling the wrong div - try

```
$('#fbfeed').click(function(){
   $('.fbfeed').hide();
});
```

instead.

Comment: sorry, I actually forgot to mention something about the commented code (which you can read in my edit).

Comment: Oh. And also, the "show/hide" code works fine. I was actually wondering about the issues I had with toggle and why it didn't work the same way.